# Ajax only working for first fetching data from while loop in php

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, while-loop

I have some comment box system. Which are coming from mysql database with specefiq post id. But whenever I write text on comment box and submit those text only first box from while loop is worked fine. But other didn't take data. I used class for those comment box division not id. What is the problem here? How can all of boxes which coming from mysql database can be worked fine for entering data as first one?

here is my code

```
while($rowCom = $resultComment->fetch_assoc()) {
    $posterID= $rowCom['poster'];
    $posterComment = $rowCom['comment'];
    $Commenttime = $rowCom['datetime'];
?>
<div class="comment-form-login">
    <input type="number" class="userPostID" name="postid" value="<?php echo $postID ?>" style="display:none;">
    <input type="number" class="userID" name="postuser" value="<?php echo $userID ?>" style="display:none;">
    <input type="number" class="LoginUserID" name="LoginUser" value="<?php echo $userLogin ?>" style="display:none;">
    <input type="text" class="usercomment leave-a-comment" placeholder="Leave a comment">
</div>
                        
<php  
} 
?>
```

Code from ajax

```
$(".leave-a-comment").on('keypress',function(e) {
    if(e.which == 13) {
        var userpostID = $(".userPostID").val();
        var userID = $(".userID").val();
        var loginuserID = $(".LoginUserID").val();
        var loginComment = $(".leave-a-comment").val();

        $.ajax({
                
            type: "POST",
            async: false,
            data: {
                    "done":1,
                    "userPOSTID":userpostID,
                    "userID":userID,
                    "loginUserID":loginuserID,
                    "LoginComment":loginComment 
            },
            success: function(data){
                $(".userPostID").val('');
                $(".userID").val('');
                $(".LoginUserID").val('');
                $(".leave-a-comment").val('');    
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: I dont see a while loop! I dont see a `url:` parameter in your Ajax post? Dont see how this could work!

Comment: @RiggsFolly PHP code in same page that's why didn't use any url. It works fine only for first query.but not for the rest of all

Comment: [Check the pink box](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/keypress_even)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of the following lines:

```
var userpostID = $(".userPostID").val();
var userID = $(".userID").val();
var loginuserID = $(".LoginUserID").val();
var loginComment = $(".leave-a-comment").val();
```

`$(".userPostID")` selects all the elements on your entire page with class `.userPostID`. Then jQuery's `.val()` function returns the value of the **first element in the set of matched elements**, which means value of your first post.

Change the code to the following:

```
var userpostID = $(this).siblings(".userPostID").val();
var userID = $(this).siblings(".userID").val();
var loginuserID = $(this).siblings(".LoginUserID").val();
var loginComment = $(this).val();
```

Do the same in your ajax success function.

Comment: Glad to hear that :)